# How do you keep up to date and find the most relevant papers?

Tags: self-study, research

What tools or methods you use to keep up with the frontier of the field? I follow some specific papers and  authors. I was wondering what's the best way to keep up to date with relevant things with so much information there's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Seminars** and **conferences** are the best ways to get exposure to working papers, in addition to following specific authors. (Some of my colleagues also follow economists on Twitter, where they sometimes post new working papers.)

In addition, subscribe to the email alerts from the **journals** in your field/interest. This will get you up to date with what comes out in the latest issues. The AEA journals (as well as *Econometrica*) will also send you the titles and abstracts of the articles; the Elsevier journals will only send you the TOC with the article titles only.

Comment: I'm not in academics but, to even have any hope, I think you have to narrow down the field considerably to some specific sub-field or even sub- sub field.. I've been looking at RE for ~3 years and I feel like there's still  more to learn about that . So catching up to the latest and greatest state of the art ( which I guess would be the topic of "learning" ) isn't even possible, atleast right now. Time in the day is also an issue. If you aren't in academics, I also highly recommend JSTOR.